# issue with saved image in a particular location in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am able to convert image to base64 string and base64 string to image . And I am saving the image to a particular location. If I run for the first time, I am getting the correct image file which I gave as input. but from the second run, whatever may be the input image I pass, I am getting only the first input image.

**Desired output :**
 I need to get back the input image that I passed.

**conversion code :**

```
public  string ImageToBase64(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}

public  Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
      imageBytes.Length);

    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    return image;
}
```

**save file code :**

```
public void retreiveAndSaveImgFile(string base64formofstr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("the incoming string :: " + base64formofstr.Length);

/*    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Base64ToImage(base64formofstr));
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
    newBitmap.SetResolution(150, 150); // resolution of the original image for which the zone template is created
    newBitmap.Save("D:\\Suraya\\TesttogetCorrectPutput\\MICR_SAMPLE.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);*/

    Base64ToImage(base64formofstr).Save("D:\\Suraya\\TesttogetCorrectPutput\\MICR_SAMPLE.tif");

}
```

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that smart with all of this but till I understand the problem you have is because of cache... As you are using the same name all time, it shows the output from the cache instead of conversion..

**First Alternate** is to add a time stamp to the name of image..
**Second Alternate** is to force the browser to reload the complete page instead of showing it from the cache..